# Property accessible from all pages but change only once per session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I don't think the title is the best description for my problem but, the problem is as following:

I have a base class like:

```
  public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
         public static ProjectDTO Project { get; set; }
         // some other code

         // Setting the project once per session.
         public void SetProject()
         {

           Project = (ProjectDTO)HttpContext.Current.Session["Project"];
           SiteMaster masterPage = Master as SiteMaster;
           masterPage.Project = Project;
         }

    }
```

And then i have an `aspx` page like:

```
public partial class SomePage: BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //callling the base method to set the project
       SetProject();
    }

    //some db method which requires the Project.Id property.
    GetSomeInfo(Project.Id)
    {
    //irelevant code
    }

}
```

Everything works fine, but, when i have 2 users online at the same time, they will obviously call the `SetProject` method, and if one of them uses `GetSomeInfo` method, the `Project.Id` property will be the latest one set, not the one from the current user session.

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

PS:

- A dirty fix would be to read the session variable every time i have to use the Project, won't be a problem, but my page has like 10 methods requiring that property (a lot of redundant code)
- A secondary fix would be to declare a public property on `SomePage` and use that, but then, i would find `Project` from the `BasePage` redundant and i don't like that approach because there are quite a few pages requiring the `Project` property and using the `BasePage` (filters, searches, etc on objects belonging to that Project)

**EDIT** After some more testing, 2 different users at the same time, and after Glubus comments, the problem happens only when the page is loading for one of the users (the user which is not loading anything will get wrong results from the database while the other user is loading a page.)

**EDIT2** The workflow is as following:
User goes to home page where a list of projects are available (read from db) -> clicks on one project (when the user clicks the project i'm setting a session variable to be read later). Then the user can see/use other data related to this project.

**EDIT3**
When a user click on a project, they will navigate to a `Dashboard` page. Here, on the `Page_Load` even i'm setting the session variable, like:

```
public partial class Dashboard : BasePage
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int projectId;
        int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["projectId"], out projectId);
        if (projectId > 0)
            {
                Session["Project"] = ProjectSvc.GetProjectById(projectId);
                SetProject();
            }
    }
}
```

ProjectDTO class:

```
public class ProjectDTO
    {
        public int idProject { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Users { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

    }
```

I'm setting the `Project` to the `Site Master` because i have a label which requires to be seen on the screen with the `Project` Name and description.

Comment: Have you tried this by accessing your page with 2 separate sessions? It seems like a huge design flaw if both Project references point to the same instance for two different sessions.

Comment: @Glubus, yes, one normal, and one incognito, but the same user (cannot change the login process to use 2 users.)

Comment: Well if you have two different sessions both using the same User, clearly stuff is going to hit the fan. You should not care about this. If this also happens for two different users something is very very wrong, and you should reconsider the way you manage sessions.

Comment: @Glubus, updated the question with some "interesting" info.

Comment: Session variables are horrible. Where does `Project` originally come from? Database? Why not save the ID to a cookie and load directly?

Comment: @ChrisPickford yes, the `Project` comes from the database, updated question with workflow.

Comment: You should restructure your application to take a project id from url / query string and only load the data needed to populate your page.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I am getting the id from the query string like: `int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["projectId"], out projectId);` but only on the first page that is shown after the user selects a project.

Comment: Why not just load the project from db on each request?

Comment: @ChrisPickford a lot of requests would be send to db because i have a lot of methods using that id. That's why i'd like to use a base class for it.

Comment: Then your application needs to be restructured because session (global) variables are never the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the Project from the current Session from all places, including WebMethods, declare a static readonly property in BasePage that directly accesses the Session.

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
             public static ProjectDTO Project 
             { 
                get {return (ProjectDTO)HttpContext.Current.Session["Project"];}
             }
             // some other code

             // Passing the Project to the Master.
             public void SetProject()
             {
               SiteMaster masterPage = Master as SiteMaster;
               masterPage.Project = Project;
             }
}
```

You can get rid of the SetProject() call altogether if you also use BasePage.Project to access the current project from the Site Master.

During testing, make sure that you are not using the same browser instance for testing. When session managements happens via cookies and you have two users logged in into the same browser instance, they will actually use the same ASP.net session.

Comment: Will test and come back with feedback!

Comment: Thanks, easy fix, shame on me i didn't think about it. I'll award the bounty tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a worst case scenario solution - but....
If you are really intent on making the Project variable accessible to all subsequent users, you maybe need to move away from sessions and just declare it as a static?

This way it will be shared application wide, retaining the last assigned value.

Comment: Sorry, my bad there, it is already static but while i was testing i changed it to normal to see the behaviour.

Comment: Well, yeah, the static property is a problem. Make it not static, so that each page instance has its own version.